# Stroke just one path in single layer independently

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes, path, stroke

This is a Photoshop question.

I created a rectangle in a layer.  Then I copied it and moved it until it touched the first one along an edge.  I would like to be able to stroke each rectangle individually.  However, when I select one path and then stroke it, the stroke goes around the outside of the two rectangles together, and the edge along which they touch is not stroked.

How can I stroke each independently?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your question you want to create to identical rectangles, both with a stroke. It sounds like you could create a rectangle with a stroke and duplicate that.

**Edit**
Convert to Smart Object and Rasterize (*Right click on the layer in the layers panel to get these options*) the layers before you bump them together. I am not having this problem at the minute but I have had similar in the past and I'm sure that this is how I overcame it.

Comment: But then when I bump them up together so they touch, the adjoining line loses its stroke.  Try it and get back to me.  Create square one and stroke it.  Duplicate it.  Then bring the 2nd so it touches the side of the first.

Comment: Convert to Smart Object and Rasterize (Right click on the layer in the layers panel to get these options) the layers before you bump them together. I am not having this problem at the minute but I have had similar in the past and I'm sure that this is how I overcame it. I'll stick this info in the question too. Let me know if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to recreate your rectangles as I understood them from your description. I can't reproduce the issue you are having, but here are some tips.

Make sure you only select one path at a time. If your rectangles are both in the same path 'layer', the stroke option will say "Stroke Subpath" rather than "Stroke Path" when you have only one rectangle selected. It might make it easier if you keep each rectangle in a separate path 'layer'. Once you have them positioned, you can copy/paste them between layers and they won't move.

[image: one layer each]

It sounds like you may have your path selection tool options [image: path select tool options]set to "add", since the shared line is being removed. This would only happen if you have multiple rectangles selected, though.

Comment: I tried messing with the path selection tool options, but no luck.  I'm making a calendar, so I'm loath to create 35 layers for each square (day).  I would rather have the 35 squares on one layer and bump them up along side each other.  I'm my comment above I suggested just what to do as a test.  Did you do that and not lose the adjoining line?  Could you post a screenshot?